# Extending an orthonormal set

Tags: vector-spaces, orthonormal

Prove that given any orthonormal set $\{e_1, \dots, e_k\}$, where $k < m$, there exists a vector $e_{k+1} \in V^m$ such that $\{e_1, \cdots, e_k, e_{k+1}\}$ is an orthonormal set.

Am unsure what properties I should use to prove this.

Comment: Do you know about Gramm-Schmidt orthonormalization algorithm ?

Comment: Yes but not sure how I would use that here

Comment: Take any vector $v$ that is linearly independant to $e_1,\ldots,e_k$, and apply Gramm-Schmidt orthonormalization to the free family $(e_1,\ldots ,e_k,v)$.

Comment: How do we know there exists a vector v that is linearly independent to this orthonormal set?

Comment: The dimension of your vector space is more than the number of vectors you have, so they can't possibly generate the whole space. Take any vector that doesn't lie in the subspace they generate.